# Can you identify these legs with the grass skirt?

Tags: part-identification

Can anyone identify these legs. I tried searching Bricklink for "legs skulls" and "legs grass skirt" but couldn't find it.
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is:

[Hips and **Reddish Brown** Legs with Lime Loincloth, Spider Knee Pads and Black Claws Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=970c88pb15#T=C&C=34) from [Sparratus](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?M=loc053):

[image]

or (as JLRishe pointed out in comments):

[Hips and **Dark Brown** Legs with Lime Loincloth, Spider Knee Pads and Black Claws Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=970c120pb07&idColor=34#T=C&C=34) from [Sparacon](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?M=loc061)

[image]

Both are from Chima sets.

Comment: The picture quality isn't great, but it looks like they're probably actually [Hips and _Dark Brown_ Legs with Lime Loincloth, Spider Knee Pads and Black Claws Pattern](https://brickscout.com/en/products/detail/4057296928248/part__970c120pb07/lime-hips-and-dark-brown-legs-with-lime-loincloth-spider-knee-pads-and-black-claws-pattern). The dark brown legs belong to [Sparacon](https://legolegendsofchima.fandom.com/wiki/Sparacon) and the reddish brown ones belong to [Sparratus](https://legolegendsofchima.fandom.com/wiki/Sparratus).